# Java runtime process waitfor does not appear to wait for

Tags: java, process, runtime

I have to write a program that is required to run several other programs via command line calls.  Program 1 produces a file that program 2 then reads.  I have followed various examples on how to do this safely but still have one annoying problem .  The code below largely works, but only if the `system.out` after the `waitfor()` is present.  If I take this out I get error (see below).  I am somewhat uncomfortable with the code if I don't know why something is happening.

Any help appreciated.

**Code:**

```
public static int executeCommandWithOutputfile(String command,
      String outputFile) {
   int exitVal = 0;

   try {
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
      Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
      Process proc = rt.exec(command);

      // any error message?
      StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(proc.getErrorStream(),
            "ERROR");

      // any output?
      StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(proc.getInputStream(),
            "OUTPUT", fos);

      // kick them off
      errorGobbler.start();
      outputGobbler.start();

      // any error???
      exitVal = proc.waitFor();
      //don't remove this system out, when I did I got errors.
      //System.out.println("ExitValue: " + exitVal);
      fos.flush();
      fos.close();
   } catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace();
   }
   return exitVal;
}
```

**Output with System.out line intact:**

```
    ExitValue: 0
    ExitValue: 0
    ExitValue: 0
    Release note complete.
```

**Output with system.out removed:**

```
    [Fatal Error] tmpRelNote2482381115742032425xml:1:1: Premature end of file.
    Error : The XML config file is not valid!
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at rwe.release.CreateReleaseNote.insertReleaseInfo(CreateReleaseNote.java:96)
        at rwe.release.CreateReleaseNote.writeReleaseNote(CreateReleaseNote.java:81)
        at rwe.release.CreateReleaseNote.<init>(CreateReleaseNote.java:30)
        at rwe.release.CreateReleaseNote.main(CreateReleaseNote.java:19)
    Process exited with exit code 1.
```

Comment: You should show the point where the exception occurs, in this case in `insertReleaseInfo()`.

Comment: You appear to be getting an error before you reach waitFor().  What do you see when you try to debug the code in a debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a race condition. The `OutputGobbler` may or may not be finished gobbling the output of the process when you call `fos.close()`. The `println` slows this thread down enough to give the gobbler time to finish processing the output of the process.

You *must* make sure the `OutputGobbler` has finished transferring all the output to the file before you close the file.

Comment: added errorGobbler.join();and outputGobbler.join(); and all now works, thanks David

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the issue is with the waitFor()?

I think the issue is with flushing the external command's OutputStream, which explains why the System.out.println() fixes the issue.  Try doing an explicit System.out.flush() after waitFor() returns.

From Process javadoc: "The created subprocess does not have its own terminal or console. All its standard io (i.e. stdin, stdout, stderr) operations will be redirected to the parent process through three streams (getOutputStream(), getInputStream(), getErrorStream())."